# Contracted forms to long forms

Tags: python, nlp

I am looking for a Python library that can take a sentence as input and convert all [contracted forms](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/shortforms.html) (a.k.a.short forms) to their long forms.

E.g. `He didn't do it` -> `He did not do it`.

More examples:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at NLTK (http://www.nltk.org/) ? If so, why it was not enough?